# How to extract data from multiple spans inside paragraphs

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

`#How to extract Hawks from span using Beautiful Soup

```
playerTeam = soup.find_all('p',attrs={'class':'player-details'})

for teams in playerTeam:
    team = teams.get('span')
    playerTeam.append(team)
```

Output:

```
<p class="player-details"><span>#10</span><span>G</span><span>Hawks</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,You can use `re` module to search particular text.

```
import bs4
import re
html_doc="""<html><p class="player-details">
<span>#10</span>
<span>G</span>
<span>Hawks</span>
</p></html>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
find_p=soup.find('p' ,class_='player-details')
findspan=find_p.find('span' ,text=re.compile("Hawks"))
print(findspan.text)
```

Output :

```
Hawks
```

Or If you want to extract all values from span try this.

```
import bs4
html_doc="""<html><p class="player-details">
<span>#10</span>
<span>G</span>
<span>Hawks</span>
</p><p class="player-details">
<span>#20</span>
<span>G</span>
<span>Hawks</span>
</p></html>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
find_p=soup.find_all('p' ,class_='player-details')

for p in find_p:
 findspan=p.find_all('span')
 for sp in findspan:
   print(sp.text)
```

Output:

```
#10
G
Hawks
#20
G
Hawks
```

Let me know if that you are looking after.

Comment: That's good but i have a whole list of teams like "Hawks" in same format  and wants to extract that specific span of whole list. Your second method is working good but extracting values of first span only.

Comment: I have updated the answer.Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
import bs4

html_doc="""<html>
<p class="player-details"><span>#10</span><span>G</span><span>Hawks</span></p>
<p class="player-details"><span>#11</span><span>H</span><span>Nicks</span></p>
</html>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
sel_p=soup.select('p.player-details')
for i in find_p:
     print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
#10
G
Hawks


#11
H
Nicks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
playerTeam_Cur = []
playerTeam = soup.find_all('p',attrs={'class':'player-details'})
for i in range(len(playerList)):
    team = playerTeam[i].find_all('span')
    playerTeam_Cur.append(team[2].text)

for x in playerTeam_Cur:
print(x)

Output:    
Hawks
Thunder
Heat
```